# selectively run doxygen in cmake

Tags: cmake, doxygen

I've got a CMakeLists.txt file that handles Doxygen generation for a software project. Its contents are:

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  set(doxyfile_in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in)
  set(doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile)
  configure_file(${doxyfile_in} ${doxyfile} @ONLY)
  add_custom_target(doc ALL
    ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${doxyfile}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM) 
endif()
```

I'd really like to only run doxygen if I'm doing an install build. Is there some straightforward way of communicating that to cmake?

Comment: Probably you have to do your calls in such a way that you only call doxygen in your install target and not in your default (?) target.

Comment: @albert Of course. The question is how to do that.

Comment: @user888379 you want to generate the doc when you call `cmake --target install`, right?

Comment: @EmiBrown I've never used cmake --target install; I always use make install. I just tried it and got the message "Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI." I've also never used the CMake GUI,,,

Comment: `cmake --build build --target install`, will simply do a `cd build && make install` if you use a Makefile generator. But it's also work with ninja etc contrary to "make install"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove the ALL from `add_custom_target()`.

```
add_custom_target(doc ALL
```

by

```
add_custom_target(doc
```

Then add

```
install(CODE
  "EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target doc)")
```

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#code

## Examples

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project(meta VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES NONE)
# ....

enable_language(CXX)
add_executable(app main.cpp)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIGDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/foo)
install(TARGETS app
  EXPORT FooTargets
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
install(EXPORT FooTargets
  NAMESPACE foo::
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)

# replace by your own code
add_custom_target(doxygen
  COMMAND echo Hello Doxygen
  VERBATIM
)

install(CODE
  "EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target doxygen)")
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Shell:

```
$ cmake -H. -Bbuild
...
$ cmake --build build --target install -- DESTDIR=install
Scanning dependencies of target app
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable app
[100%] Built target app
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: install/usr/local/bin/app
-- Installing: install/usr/local/lib/cmake/foo/FooTargets.cmake
-- Installing: install/usr/local/lib/cmake/foo/FooTargets-noconfig.cmake
Scanning dependencies of target doxygen
Hello Doxygen
Built target doxygen
```

Comment: I don't think this is gonna work, install is not a high level target, it is a built in one

Comment: Interesting - I was wondering about wedging build logic into an install(). I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Mizux, Nice, I didn't know about the `install(CODE ...) ` command, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with an approach that divides the work between add_custom_command() and add_custom_target():

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  set(doxyfile_in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in)
  set(doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile)
  configure_file(${doxyfile_in} ${doxyfile} @ONLY)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/doxygen.stamp
    DEPENDS ${doxyfile}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${doxyfile}
    COMMAND cmake -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/doxygen.stamp
    COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
    VERBATIM)
  add_custom_target(doc ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/doxygen.stamp)
endif()
```

It's not exactly what I originally was asking for, but it's good enough for my purposes. I'm not going to accept this answer just yet, in case someone chimes in with an answer that **does** more exactly address my initial request.